# Как заменить div на span с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью jquery автоматически при загрузке страницы заменить строку `<div id='name'>` на `<span>`. Поясню. Движок автоматически генерирует весь контент в `<div id='name'>`. А у меня страница состоит из нескольких секций со своими блоками с `id`, которые и обертываются в этот общий системный `<div id='name'>`, и как следствие - многое на странице не работает. Благодарю за подсказку!

---

Блоку  назначены следующие стили: `position:static` и `display:inline`

Comment: Не понял. Чем вашим блокам мешает оборачивание в div id="name", не могли бы вы пояснить? Заменить-то можно, но это это будет жестокий костыль и хочется сперва понять вашу проблему.

Comment: могу точно сказать, что причина не в том, что блоки находятся внутри #name. Косвенно - возможно. Но решать нужно где-то в другом месте, а не заменой блока. К примеру, у вас могут быть прописаны стили для элементов внутри #name. В этом случае, убирать #name - неправильный подход, ведь достаточно исправить стили. Вариантов огромное количество. Чтобы разобраться - нужно увидеть своими глазами или хотя бы увидеть пример кода.

Comment: И разберись конкретнее: что значит "блоки невидимы"? Они есть в коде страницы или нет? Если есть - посмотрите, какие стили делают их невидимыми и найдете ответ.

Comment: Еще удостоверьтесь, что у вас на странице один блок #name.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на эту страницу или хоть пример кода и я уверен, что Вам подскажут правильное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы запускалось сразу после загрузки скрипта.

```
 (function(){
  $('div#name').replaceWith('<span></span>');
 })();
```

Comment: Попробуйте данный код , который заменяет вставить в ready функцию от JQuery